# Split numpy 2D Array with Unknown Length to 3D Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split, reshape

I have a (18, 10525) numpy array.
18 columns with 10525 rows, but the number of rows is not always the same and I must slice the array into 18 columns and groups or windows of 200 rows to feed it to AI.

For example I would like to do

```
data = np.ones((18, 10525))
data.reshape(-1,18,200)
```

But 10525 isn't divisible by 200 so I get a `ValueError`. I would like to get a zero padded array of shape (-1,18,200). I.e. add zeros to data until I can do `.reshape(-1,18,200)`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect numpy to do? There is no integer i such that i*18*200=10525. You could add nans until it does or throw away a bit of data.

Comment: `(18, 10525)` is generally accepted to mean 18 rows, 10k columns.

Comment: Please post an mcve. Your prose is ambiguous. And yes, you can't reshape something that's not a multiple of 200 to have size 200. You need to specify exactly what you want

Comment: @MadPhysicist I need to pass arrays of 18 columns and 200 rows to pytorch prediction and I need the entire array, maybe to add zeros to the last array

Comment: Post a [mcve] when you figure it out past "maybe". Also, there are dozens of questions about splitting arrays into chunks already on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to fill with zeros here is your solution

```
data = np.ones((18, 10525))

old_size = np.prod(data.shape)
rounded_up_size = (old_size//(18*200)+1)*18*200

reshaped_arr = np.empty(rounded_up_size)
reshaped_arr[:old_size] = data.reshape(-1)
reshaped_arr[old_size:] = 0

reshaped_arr.reshape(-1,18,200)
```

Notice that I avoided copying all the data. It's just a view on the old data.